# Can we create data filter on the basis on behavioural data via data filter?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can we create a data filter on the basis of behavioural data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using either data from [data views](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) (open, click, bounce, unsubscribe, etc) to create your own filter logic using SQL or you can use [measures](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_measures.htm&type=5&language=en_US):

> A measure is a unit of subscriber behavior that you define in Email
> Studio. For example, if you use dynamic from addresses on an email
> job, the tracking for the job is all together. Contact your Marketing
> Cloud account representative for information on enabling this feature.
> After you create a measure, you can include the measure as criteria in
> a data filter to segment a subscriber list using the measure. Some
> examples of measures include:
>
> 1. Total opens in last 30 days
> 2. Total click-throughs in last 30 days
> 3. Hard bounces in the last month
> 4. Unique unsubscribes in the last 30 days.

To create your own logic using SQL, go to Automation Studio > Activities > Query Activity.

To use Measures, go to Email Studio > Subscribers > Measures.

Comment: @SaloniArora - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!